# Why are there zeros between numbers and Dataframe titles?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Somehow some "0" come up below the title of my Dataframe when i append to a dictionary and then concatenate it to a Dataframe...

```
                                  Open      High       Low     Close
                            0         0         0         0
Time                                                       
2013.10.29 00:00:00 -0.001090 -0.003290 -0.006910 -0.006255
2013.10.30 00:00:00 -0.006144 -0.005078 -0.003908 -0.000512
2013.10.31 00:00:00 -0.000442  0.001646  0.002732 -0.000985
2013.11.01 00:00:00 -0.000842 -0.000017  0.000998  0.001132
2013.11.04 00:00:00  0.003941  0.005085  0.005387  0.009340
```

```
    df={} 

    for name in series.columns: 
        # .... do some series manipulations and convert it to numpy arrays and to lists and so on...
        # => create "list_" which is a list of numbers


        df[name]=pd.DataFrame(list_.copy())  

    df=pd.concat(df,axis=1)  
    return df
```

Comment: Can you supply all the code or a minimal example?

Comment: @cmosig already solved (see below). But I appreceate your involvement :-) stay healty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
    df={} 

    for name in series.columns: 
        # .... do some series manipulations and convert it to numpy arrays and to lists and so on...
        # => create "list_" which is a list of numbers


        df[name]=pd.Series(list_.copy())   # <--- Here, use a series instead :)

    df=pd.concat(df,axis=1)  
    return df
```